How to Make the Top Plane of a 3D Histogram Square in R's hist3D Function?
I am using the hist3D function from the plot3D package in R to create a 3D bar plot.
However, the top plane of the bars in the plot is rectangular, and I want it to be square.
Below is my reproducible code and data:
library(plot3D)

dd2 = structure(c(1, 3.07, 1.87, 4.6, 5.71, 0.68), dim = 2:3, dimnames = list(
  c("正常", "异常"), c("<120/80", "120-139/80-89", "≥140/90"
  )))

m2 <- matrix(1:length(dd2), 
             nrow = nrow(dd2))
colors <- c("#3d6ab4", "#deb44c", "#f47d1f", "#84c347", "#78cae5", "#66468c")

hist3D(z = dd2, 
       scale = FALSE,
       expand = 0.3,
       bty = "g", 
       theta = 15, 
       phi = 20, 
       d = 2, 
       r = 20,
       border = 'white',
       shade = 0.1, 
       ltheta = 40, 
       space = 0.9, 
       ticktype = "detailed", 
       zmin = 0, 
       zlim = c(0, max(dd2)), 
       col = colors, 
       colvar = m2, 
       colkey = FALSE, 
       axes = FALSE 
)

How can I modify this code to ensure that the top plane of each bar in the 3D histogram is square instead of rectangular?
Thank you in advance for your help!

You could experiment with providing x and y and changing space. This seems to be close to squares: ... x = c(1, 1.75), y = c(1, 2, 3), space = 0.6, ... but the plot looks a bit different obviously.
